# Unable get the sheet zoom value in apache poi

Tags: apache-poi

In apache poi we are able setting zoom value using sheet.setZoom(120). But How we will get zoom values when we copy/clone same sheet. I can not able to find a method srcSheet.getZoom();. what is alternative for this method?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What can we do if `apache poi` lacks a method? We could take a look how it does coding similar methods. For example [XSSFSheet..setZoom](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_3_17_FINAL/src/ooxml/java/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFSheet.java?view=markup#l2830) does nothing else than setting the `zoomScale` of the default [CTSheetView](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.poi/ooxml-schemas/1.1/org/openxmlformats/schemas/spreadsheetml/x2006/main/CTSheetView.java). So if we would get the default sheet view, we could do the opposite and get the `zoomScale`.

Example:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTSheetView;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class ExcelXSSFSheetZoom {

 static long getZoom(XSSFSheet sheet) throws Exception {
  Method getDefaultSheetView = XSSFSheet.class.getDeclaredMethod("getDefaultSheetView"); 
  getDefaultSheetView.setAccessible(true); 
  CTSheetView sheetview = (CTSheetView)getDefaultSheetView.invoke(sheet);
  return sheetview.getZoomScale();
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
  Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet();
  sheet.setZoom(120);

  System.out.println(getZoom((XSSFSheet)sheet));

  wb.write(new FileOutputStream("ExcelXSSFSheetZoom.xlsx"));
  wb.close();

 }

}
```

---

Current Apache poi versions have not zero argument method `private CTSheetView getDefaultSheetView()` but only only `private CTSheetView getDefaultSheetView(final boolean create)`. So same for current Apache POI versions would must be:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTSheetView;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class ExcelXSSFSheetZoom {

 static long getZoom(XSSFSheet sheet) throws Exception {
  Method getDefaultSheetView = XSSFSheet.class.getDeclaredMethod("getDefaultSheetView", boolean.class); 
  getDefaultSheetView.setAccessible(true); 
  CTSheetView sheetview = (CTSheetView)getDefaultSheetView.invoke(sheet, true);
  return sheetview.getZoomScale();
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
  Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet();
  sheet.setZoom(120);

  System.out.println(getZoom((XSSFSheet)sheet));

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("ExcelXSSFSheetZoom.xlsx");
  wb.write(out);
  out.close();
  wb.close();

 }

}
```

Comment: Brilliant...Thank you saved lot of time.